# Laravel Nested Query for Phone Brand and Phone Model from 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel

[image: phone_brands]

[image: phone_models]

I have 2 tables
1st) Brand Name of Mobile phone
2nd) - Model Name for Brand Name

How can i get output like below. I need JSON output as i am creating dropdown button in Android (Flutter) App based on nested inputs

```
{
      "phone_brand_name": "Apple",
      "phone_brand_model_name": [
        "Apple iPhone 11",
        "Apple iPhone 11 Pro",
        "Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max",
      ]
    },
```

I have below hasMany relation :

```
class PhoneBrand extends Model
{
    
    public function phoneModels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PhoneModelsController');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you setup the relationships? From the tables it looks like it's a one-to-many relationship. between the two tables. Have a look at  this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many Try to set the relationship as explained in the doc. Querying examples are there as well.

Comment: Yes, i am using relationships

Answer (score 0):

The hasmany has to be linked with the Model not the controller;

so if everything else is set up correctly.

```
class PhoneBrand extends Model
{

    public function phoneModels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PhoneModel');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what should be query should be used to get the output.

Comment: If everything is setup as it should, than simply :

$phoneBrand = PhoneBrand::where('phone_brand_name' , 'Apple')->first();

than you can access the phoneModels with $phoneBrand->phoneModels ; 

using this you can create a JSON however you may need it.